# Adding custom wms layer to Here map

Tags: here-api, geoserver, bounding-box, wms, here-maps-rest

I want to add a custom WMS layer from my GeoServer to Here map in Javascript. I found an example of adding [custom-tile-overlay](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/infoBubbles/custom-tile-overlay), but how can I get bounding box which is required in WMS GetMap request. Is there any way that I can get bounding box of the current viewport in Here maps?

Answer (score 1):

The current bounding box of the map using HERE JS API 3.1 can be retrieved using the following piece of code

```
map.getViewModel().getLookAtData().bounds.getBoundingBox()
```

This would return a H.geo.Rect object containing the bounding box coordinates.